# Is it possible to solve this equation with logarithms and exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, problem-solving

$$-\frac{1}{3}\log(4x-12)+6=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^x $$

Out of all the logarithm laws I've learned (which is pretty limited), I have not found a way to solve for what x is yet. Can someone verify that this equation can be solved, and provide a few hints and pointers on the method/how to do so?

Comment: That looks like one equation, not a system.

Comment: remember it is assumed $10^\text{variable} = 4x - 12$

Comment: To what base are the logarithms taken? Is $x$ supposed to be an integer? [or how is the power of a negative number defined]

Comment: What is $x$, real?  How do you want to define $-1/2$ to irrational power?

Comment: Well this is only Grade 12, so my best guess it only real and rational numbers. Both equations are separate, and I'm trying to find the point of intersection. The log is of base 10, the common logarithm.

Comment: but $(-1/2)^x$ is not defined for all real numbers since $-1/2<0$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, sorry, poor mathematics student here. I don't understand your post. Can you elaborate using more elementary terms?

Comment: yes thx for your hint

Comment: You should not write $\dfrac{-1}{2}^x$ if you mean $\left(\dfrac{-1}2\right)^x$.  Properly, the notation you've used means $\dfrac{-(1^x)}2$, and that is different. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: my question is : can you please say what the right most term is

Comment: $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^x$ or another?

Comment: I'm new here, so I don't know anything about formatting. Some users have edit my original equation and made it clearer. And yes, I mean (-1/2)^x or -0.5^x

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, yeah, that's the one.

Comment: I just edited the question to make the right side as in the original unedited question: $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^x$. Please tell me if this is incorrect.

Comment: Which is it: (-1/2)^x or -0.5^x? They are *not* the same, since the negative sign is in different places.

Comment: thus we can only solve your equation in the set of integer numbers

Comment: since $4x-12>0$ it must be $x\geq 4$

Comment: @RoryDaulton, right now, the right side is correct.

Comment: i would say draw the graph of $-\frac{1}{3}\log(4x-12)+6$ and $(-1/2)^x$ for $4,5,6...$ and search where an intersection point can be

Comment: But I also need to prove this algebraically as well, and I'm stumped on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

for $$x=2m$$ and $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ we get the equation
$$-\frac{1}{2}\log(8m-12)+6=\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^m$$
solving that we get $$m=1.25\cdot 10^{17}$$
in the other case we set $$x=2n+1$$ and we have
$$-\frac{1}{2}\log(8n-8)+6=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n$$
and we also have $$1.25\cdot 10^{17}$$ maybe both results are not exact.

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea is to notice that, due to the very slow-growing nature of the logarithmic function, combined with the highly-accelerated decrease of an exponential function with sub-unitary basis, the equation does not possess any small-valued solutions, thus becoming ultimately equivalent to solving $\log(4x-12)\approx6\cdot3=18\iff x\approx3+\dfrac{a^{18}}4$ , where *a* represents the unspecified basis of your logarithm, presumably either $2$, or $10$, or *e*.